# Run a command on each file in a directory

Tags: opencv, process, batch-file, blob

I need to run a command on each file in a directory. Since I want to process hundreds of videos, I will find it easier using a batch script.

The command looks like this:

```
blobtrack_sample.exe fg=FG_0 bd=BD_CC btgen=RawTracks track=E:\opencv\tracks\video1.txt bta=TrackDist btavi=E:\opencv\btavi\test.avi E:\sample\video1.avi
```

Where `btavi=` indicates the output file and the last argument indicates the input file.
The name of the output file for each file must be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate through all files in the some folder, do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set EXE_FILE=E:\opencv\build\bin\Debug\blobtrack_sample.exe
set INPUT_PATH=E:\sample\
set TRACKS_PATH=E:\opencv\tracks\
set OUTPUT_PATH=E:\opencv\btavi\
set COUNT=0
pushd %INPUT_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set /a COUNT+=1
    echo Processing %%f, track=%%~nf.txt, btavi=test!COUNT!%%~xf
    %EXE_FILE% fg=FG_0 bd=BD_CC btgen=RawTracks track=%TRACKS_PATH%\%%~nf.txt bta=TrackDist btavi=%OUTPUT_PATH%\test!COUNT!%%~xf %%f
)
popd
```

The loop takes each file, puts it into the variable `%%f` and calls your blobtrack_sample.exe with `%%f` being one of its arguments. Also, the name of the executable in `EXE_FILE`.

To run this script, copy-paste this code into a file with a ".bat" extension and execute it. Hope it helps!